# Google Apps: Remove naked redirect

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine and I would like my web site to be available at http://example.com and not http://www.example.com. Under the domain settings there is a forward of the naked domain, so that example.com is redirected to www.example.com - how do I remove this forward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently no longer possible to link a domain without a subdomain to Google App Engine. I found the answer on Stack Owerflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain.